# JS code blocks the normal functioning of the page

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, artificial-intelligence, block

I wrote a js code with an AI library. The code have to return a prediction, but while the js code is doing this job the website can't be used. It's blocked until the prediction is done.

How can I make the js code working 'asynchronously', so that the user can use the website as usual?

Thank you!!

Comment: Sounds like a potential use case for [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is the library that is blocking.
In that case, you can move the function to a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), this would work by having the page send a message to the Web Worker with the needed parameters, and the Worker does the necessary calculations and sends it back to the page.

Comment: Thank you! It's a great idea. But now I've an other question :). My code need a library, so how can a js file (using Web Worker API) import the library it needs?

Comment: @MatteoPitrelli You can use [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)